# How to check if the current file is the main one in javascript (iOS Instruments UI Automator)

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, instruments, android-uiautomator

In Python there is a neat thing like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    runTests()
```

So this runs `runTests()` only if the file was run separately and not imported. When the file will be imported it will not run the tests.

So I want to create some kind of modules for my tests in Instruments UI Automation - but I also want to test the module itself.

**Is there any global variable that I can check to see if the current file is being run as a main file or as an imported one?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, unfortunately the answer is **no**. If you are looking for something like the `__name__` variable in python it does not exist. A hacky workaround that isn't really a solution to your problem (as it would require you to edit your test script before running), you could set a global variable prior to your inputs

```
var BEING_RUN = false;
#import "path/to/jsFile.js"
```

with an if statement in each file

```
//BEING_RUN = true;
if (BEING_RUN) {
    doStuff();
}
```

and you could uncomment `BEING_RUN = true;` only on the file(s) being run. Again, this is not really a solution but it may suit your needs.

My recommendation would be to structure your test library in such a way that you don't import things from files that also contain UI tests. So you should put functions and other things that are used by your tests in files that get imported, and only have the actual simulation of user interaction in your test files. I'd also suggest checking out tuneup.js (http://www.tuneupjs.org/) it makes iOS UI Automation much more pleasant.